# Getting Memory Leak in textFields

Tags: objective-c

Here Im Getting memory leak at

```
eventTextField.keyboardAppearance  = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
```

I declared the textfield globally and I allocated the text field in CellForRowAtIndex and my code is:

```
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    eventTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 300, 50)];
    eventTextField.placeholder = @"Event Name:";
    [eventTextField setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    eventTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    eventTextField.keyboardAppearance  = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
    eventTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    eventTextField.delegate=self;
    if(isRightButton == YES)
    {
        eventTextField.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        eventTextField.enabled = YES;
    }
    if([event.eventName length] > 0)
    {
        eventTextField.text = event.eventName;
    }
    else
    {
        eventTextField.text = @"";
    }
    [elementView addSubview:eventTextField];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

and I release the textfield in dealloc.
when Im checking the object allocations it showing leak at:
eventTextField.keyboardAppearance  = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;

guys please help me to get out of this.
Anyone's help will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add:

```
[eventTextField release]
```

after:

```
[elementView addSubview:eventTextField];
```

This works because addSubview will retain the subview and release it when the view itself is released, so you can safely release the textfield after adding it to the view.

*Golden Rule*: Anytime you call **alloc** or **copy** or **retain**, you should always call **release** (or **autorelease**).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's because every time cellForRowAtIndexPath get's called, your allocating memory to eventTextField, without first releasing what you had before.

Check if eventTextField is nil before doing the alloc.